# Material Color Reveal via Radial Reaction

Tags: android, material-design

In Android, a feature called radial reaction exists (find it at https://material.google.com/motion/choreography.html#choreography-radial-reaction).

After a bit of research, I discovered that we can use this to reveal views (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html and http://pulse7.net/android/android-create-circular-reveal-animation-and-ripple-effect-like-whatsapp/).

Is it possible to reveal a certain color, instead of a view? (For example, change the background color to red when the user clicks the layout)

Answer (score 1):

For now, only revealing a view is supported out-of-the box in ViewAnimationUtils https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html

You could have your layout file define two different background layouts (LinearLayouts for example).  The circular reveal would reveal whichever view you need.